# Why did Matuzak say, "You don't count"?

Tags: timecop

In time travel movie *Timecop (1994)*, Max Walker returns to a present time and meets his boss Matuzak.
He finds his company now running by Senator McComb. Actually, 
He was send with Fielding to a past to find the cause of disturbance
in the time ripples.

> Max Walker: A guy named Parker and Fielding.
>
> Matuzak: Do I know them?
>
> Max Walker:  Fielding was with me. You sent her.
>
> Matuzak: I don't like this guy one little bit, but who the hell  do
>   you think......I can sell this story to without a smoking  gun and
>   about 50 eyewitnesses?
>
> Max Walker: How about one?
>
> Matuzak: **You don't count**.